# MongoDB Convert this to key-value pairs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The output of my mongo query after applying groupyby is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "FAIL",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "PASS",
    "count": 3
  }
]
```

How can I convert this to key value pairs like this:

```
[
  metric_count:{      
  "FAIL":2,
  "PASS":3,
  "TOTAL":5   //sum of pass count and fail count
 }
]
```

[**MongoDB Playground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eqJimurMmwt)

Comment: Plz update your question with full query along with the shema, above data is insufficient to help.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat  Added mongodb playground link

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal - please add any relevant information directly to your question, not as a link to somewhere offsite. That link could eventually disappear, rendering this question incomplete. And in general, nobody should have to leave this site to fully understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB aggregation has a flexibility in the constructing of objects within pipeline. This following pipeline will help you to construct the result object you want.

*However, if you are writing program, I suggest you to write a small function convert array object to an*

First, to find total, I add a `$group` stage with `_id: null` to **pipeline**.

```js
[
  ...your stages
  {  
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "total": {
          "$sum": "$count"
        }
        "stats": {
          "$push": {
            "k": "$_id",
            "v": "$count"
          }
        },
      }
    },
  }
]
```

not only finding total, I also prepared an array object compatible to an operator `$arrayToObject` which help me make the final object.

Then the following **projection** make things righ.

```js
[
  ...your stages
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$count"
      },
      "stats": {
        "$push": {
          "k": "$_id",
          "v": "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "metric_count": {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          "$concatArrays": [
            "$stats",
            [
              {
                "k": "TOTAL",
                "v": "$total"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

As you see, I nesting **pipeline operators** in **projection stage** to contract the result object as we want. The `$concatArray` concat **stats** and **total** together in uniform array form then `$arrayToObject` convert array to final object.

I hope you will find something useful with my **pipeline**.